# strip a word when is a single word only, not part of a composite word

Tags: php, preg-replace, strip

I have the following function, I want it to strip "alpha" when is a single word only
and not a part of a composite word like "alphadog". Now instead I just see "dog" and it's not good. Any help?

```
    function stripwords($string) 
{ 
  // build pattern once 
  static $pattern = null; 
  if ($pattern === null) { 
    // pull words to remove from somewhere 
    $words = array('alpha', 'beta', '-');  
    // escape special characters 
    foreach ($words as &$word) { 
      $word = preg_quote($word, '#'); 
    } 
    // combine to regex 
    $pattern = '#\b(' . join('|', $words) . ')\b\s*#iS'; 
  } 

  $print = preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
  list($firstpart)=explode('+', $print);
  return $firstpart;

}
```

edit: hi, i have another problem... i've edited above with the new version of the function: it strips words, adjust whitespaces and then does something else i need, but it doesn't remove dashes (or minus)... what's wrong? i tried something but no avail...thanks

Comment: Your code as originally posted was some of the ugliest I've seen. Take the time to make it readable and you'll have a better chance at getting answers.

Comment: sorry, but it's not my mistake...or not completely. I don't know why, when i put code on rows, bottom code goes out of the box...

Comment: understood, it's enough to highlight the text and click on the code brackets icon...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
$pattern = '#' . join('|', $words) . '#iS';
```

Should be this:

```
$pattern = '#\b' . join('\b|\b', $words) . '\b#iS';
```

Comment: You should create a new question for a new problem.  Get rid of the `\s*` - it wasn't there originally.  Other people might not understand why these answers exist for the new question since the new question has these answers incorporated.  People tend to look at new questions without any answers so you won't get as many people helping you if you do this either.

Answer (score 4):

Use this regexp pattern

`/\balpha\b/`

`\b` stands for "word boundary", it means it will match the word by separate (if the word is surrounded by word separators).

Hope this helps

Comment: that is... how to input into that example? if i write `$words = array('/\balpha\b/', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta');` alpha is not stripped out...

Comment: i always need the array, but for some words i need to strip as seen... for example "of" and not "off" that remains f only...