# replace a word in a sentence

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a sentence like this :

```
Stan, Stanley, Stan!
```

I would like to replace all words "Stan" by Peter to have something like that

```
Peter, Stanley, Peter!
```

Here is my issue : Stanley must not be replaced because this is not the word Stan !

Right now I do something like that :

```
$txt = preg_replace(array('/Stan/i', '/Jack/i'), array('Peter', 'Jennifer'), $txt);
```

but what I need is a regexp to match only a single word (wich means my word is not immediatly followed by a letter).

I've tried something like this /Stan([^[A-Za-z])/i but this render :

```
Peter Stanley, Peter
```

Some punctuation are missing

Comment: Maybe this post can help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566176/strip-a-word-when-is-a-single-word-only-not-part-of-a-composite-word

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use word boundaries (`\b`) for this;

```
/\bStan\b/ig
```

Will match `Stan`, but not `Stanley`.

[Demo](http://regexr.com?307v9)

Answer (score 4):

`\b` means [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

This regex should work:

```
\bStan\b
```

[RegExr Demo](http://regexr.com?307v6)